# snort: how to write one or more rules to capture successive packets?

Tags: snort

Say I have a rule like this

alert tcp A_IP any -> B_IP 80 (msg:"test"; sid:10000;)

this will log the first packet from A_IP to B_IP that triggered this rule; what I want to do is when a packet triggers a rule, the rule should log successive bidirectional packets from A_IP and to B_IP and B_IP to A_IP. How can I do that? flowbits and tag can do this? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could do this with a dynamic rule:

```
activate tcp 192.168.10.10 any -> 192.168.20.20 80 (activates:1; msg:"test", sid:10000';)

dynamic tcp 192.168.10.10 any <> 192.168.20.20 80 (activated_by:1; count:50;)
```

This will wait for a packet to hit coming from `192.168.10.10` to `192.168.20.20` on port `80` and when that happens it will activate the dynamic rule which will log the next 50 packets bi directionally.